# PHP not writing client IP to file

Tags: php

I cant figure out why it wont write the client IP address to the file, everything else works.

```
<?php 
$myFile = "ips.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'a') or die("can't open file");
fwrite($fh, $_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST']);
fclose($fh);
echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];


?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `REMOTE_HOST` != `REMOTE_ADDR`

Comment: REMOTE_HOST contains the hostname of the ip (obtained by reverse dns lookup) in the REMOTE_ADDR.
If you're using Apache, you might need to turn on HostnameLookups to get the hostname.
Otherwise you may simply need to change REMOTE_HOST to REMOTE_ADDR in your fwrite command if all you want is the ip.

Comment: echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST']; works?

Comment: sorry i was mistaken, you was correct, a silly mistake on my part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe `fwrite($fh, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);` ?

Why do you think that if `echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];` works, 
`fwrite($fh, $_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST']);` should too?

Try `echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST'];` first and see if it outputs something.

My guess: just change `_HOST` to `_ADDR` in fwrite as I said in the beginning.